# How to use tailwindcss in npm package

Tags: javascript, npm, tailwind-css

I'm working on my first package.
The package has a playground, where I can test the Datatable component. Everything works as expected there.
Then I have a project, that will depend on this package. In the project, the dropdown has unlimited height, because tw class `max-h-64` is not imported in the project.

If I extend project's `tailwind.config.js` to this:

```
content: [
    './src/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}',
    './node_modules/mynew-ui/dist/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}'
],
```

it works, however it should come with package, so other users won't be bothered with this installation step.

How to include tailwind classes used by the package in its build directory?

package's package.json

```
{
    "name": "mynew-ui",
    "version": "0.1.2",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "vite build && npm run package",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "package": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-package && publint",
        "prepublishOnly": "npm run package",
        "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
        "lint": "prettier --check . && eslint .",
        "format": "prettier --write ."
    },
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
            "svelte": "./dist/index.js"
        }
    },
    "files": [
        "dist",
        "!dist/**/*.test.*",
        "!dist/**/*.spec.*"
    ],
    "peerDependencies": {
        "svelte": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^3.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^2.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/package": "^2.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^3.0.0",
        "@types/eslint": "8.56.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
        "eslint": "^8.56.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte": "^2.35.1",
        "postcss": "^8.4.32",
        "postcss-load-config": "^5.0.2",
        "prettier": "^3.1.1",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^3.1.2",
        "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.5.9",
        "publint": "^0.1.9",
        "svelte": "^4.2.7",
        "svelte-check": "^3.6.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.6",
        "tslib": "^2.4.1",
        "typescript": "^5.0.0",
        "vite": "^5.0.11"
    },
    "svelte": "./dist/index.js",
    "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "bits-ui": "^0.18.1",
        "clsx": "^2.1.0",
        "latinize": "^2.0.0",
        "tailwind-merge": "^2.2.1",
        "tailwind-variants": "^0.2.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read the [guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite)?

Comment: you pointed to the tailwind installation guide. that was followed in both the package and the project. am i missing something?

Comment: Did you add ```@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;```?

Comment: yes of course. as i said, it works in the package's playground. it doesnt work in the project that installs the package.